# Empty response for JWT login Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, redis, jwt

I'm trying to make a simple authentication system on my Node.js API. Actually, I had the login endpoint working like a charm with JWT, but I also wanted to implement a logout function (and not have to wait for the token to expire) so I looked up how to achieve it.

After doing an exhaustive research on how to do it from the server side, I decided to install the [jwt-redis package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-redis), which is suposed to not only repeat the entire functionallity of jsonwebtoken, but also store tokens in Redis and be able to destroy them with a simple method.

The fact is that now, after following the instructions on its readme, and although the endpoint is returning a successful status when testing with Postman, the response body (where the access token should be) is empty.

I attach my code below.

```
async login(req, res) {
    try {
        const redis = require('redis');
        const JWTR =  require('jwt-redis').default;
        //ES6 import JWTR from 'jwt-redis';
        const redisClient = redis.createClient();
        const jwtr = new JWTR(redisClient);
        redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
            console.log("Error " + err)
        })
        await redisClient.connect()

        console.log('email:' + req.body.email)
        console.log('hola')
        let user = await this.adapter.getByLogin(req.body.email)
        if (!user) return res.status(404).json({ Error: 'Recurso no encontrado' })

        const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
        console.log(req.body.password, user.password)
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (error, result) => {
            console.log(error, result)

            if (error) return res.status(404).json({ Error: 'Recurso no encontrado' })
            if (!result) return res.status(404).json({ Error: 'Recurso no encontrado' })

            delete user.password

            var payload = { jti: req.body.email }

            const accessToken = jwtr.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
            //console.log('accessToken:' + JSON.stringify(accessToken))
            res.json(accessToken)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Recurso no encontrado', stacktrace: error })
    }
}
```

Please, take in care that I'm pretty new in JavaScript and Back-end development, so probably it is due to a dummie mistake. Anyway, I will appreciate your help, either if you have worked with this library before and you know where the error is, or you have any other idea of how I can make both login and logout work properly using JSON web token.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot destroy an token, it will always be valid until u change the private key of signing. you can make a blaklist with redis this is possible

Answer (score 1):

The sign function of the jwt-redis package returns a promise, so you need to use either await or then in order to get the result of it.

First, in order to use await, you have to make the compare function's callback be async like

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, async (error, result) => {}
```

after that, add the await keyword before the sign function call

```
const accessToken = await jwtr.sign(payload, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time and quick response, Eduardo.
I have tried both `await` and `then` as you suggested, but now when making a request Postman gets stuck at "Sending" unti I close the Node server. Then, `Error: read ECONNRESET` appears in the console.
Any ideas of what could be happening?

Comment: Furthermore, user e-mail and password as shown at the terminal, as well as `undefined: true` (don't know if its OK).

Comment: @treblast, what happens if you use console.log(accessToken) when using await keyword?

Comment: nothing happens. Console still shows "hola", user email + password and the `undefined true`, but not the access token...

Comment: can you please share the version of redis and jwt-redis packages? I've created an example here using both, and the solution works fine

Comment: Hi, I finally got the sign part working (thanks to your help). But now, I am not able to verify the token when I make a call to and endpoint that requires authentication. I have an async function which is called everytime an API request needs to be authorized, and here I create and connect the redis client (apparently successfully), but it gets stuck again when I use the `jwtr.verify` method (passing as arguments both the tokens and the secret key). I know it because everything I put inside its callback is not printed at console. Any idea?